# Most efficient way to add a model with lots of columns to SQL using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to using Entity Framework/C#

Right now I have something like this (which in of itself isn't that bad, but my question is more about larger additions) -

```
public void addToDB(SampleModel model)
        {
            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    SampleAddition dbaddition = new SampleAddition();

                    dbaddition.field1 = model.field1;
                    dbaddition.field2 = model.field2;
                    dbaddition.field3 = model.field3;
                    dbaddition.field4 = model.field4;

                    db.Entry(dbaddition).State = EntityState.Added;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```

I was wondering if there's a more "clean" way of doing this? Something sort of like this? Or any other alternatives, just seeing what my options are.

```
foreach (var i in model) {
   dbaddition[i] = model.field[i];
}
```

Thanks for (any potential) answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a C# language solution any better that what you have.  You can implement a mapper using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netframework-4.8), but most people just leave the mapping code explicit, as you have it, or use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).